# How to check if condition in JSF tag

Tags: jsf

```
<h:commandLink value="next" action="#{student.getNext()}"  rendered="#{! (student.maximumSize<=student.idvalue.size)}" ></h:commandLink>
```

But I'm getting error in student.maximumSize<=student.idvalue.size

<= What can I  replace here .. ??

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Syntax error in EL
 - The value of attribute "rendered" associated with an element type "h:commandLink" must not contain the '<' 
  character.
 - EL syntax error: Expecting expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best is to remove the `!` and use `gt`

```
<h:commandLink rendered="#{student.maximumSize gt student.idvalue.size}" value="next" action="#{student.getNext()}"></h:commandLink>
```

or try this

```
<h:commandLink rendered="#{not (student.maximumSize le student.idvalue.size)}" value="next" action="#{student.getNext()}"></h:commandLink>
```

Here the el expressions that should be used instead of the signs like `==` `<` `>` etc...

```
==  -->  eq
!=  -->  ne
<   -->  lt
>   -->  gt
<=  -->  le
>=  -->  ge
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change '<=' to 'le', or use the &lt; syntax for the <.